# How can I download a blob url from osmosis video

Tags: url, blob, osmosis

Is there any chrome extension or software which can be used to download the playing video.

```
<video id="vjs-videoplayer-0_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" 
style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto" tabindex="-1" 
preload="auto" src="blob:https://www.osmosis.org/e4c809e7-8690-4d14-bc42- 
75f4116e8057"></video>
```